# How to link a cshtml page using href in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, href

I want to link a Menu.cshtml page using an anchor-tag with an href so that whenever I click on the menu link in the navbar it should direct me to Menu.cshtml. I have tried a few times using this code but i am not able to do it. Here is the code i am using:

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="~/Views/Home/Menu.cshtml">Menus</a>
```

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink("Menus", "Menu", "yourController", null, new { @class = "page-scroll" })` and add a controller method named `Menu` that return the view.

Comment: i have to add a controller even if i am using this as a link in the navbar?? i am a beginner in mvc can u please explain me a little?

Comment: When You place a `Menu.cshtml` inside the folder `Home`, the convention is that you have defined a `Home` controller with a `Menu` action.

Comment: Yes. The method would be just `public ActionResult Menu() { return View(); }` in the `HomeController`. In MVC, you don't navigate to files, you navigate to methods that return views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try to use the [ActionLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx) html helper and let this way the framework to produce the correct link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Menus","Menu","Home", null, new { @class = "page-scroll" })
```

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET MVC you can't directly link to a view. That would defeat the whole purpose of MVC. In ASP.NET MVC, the controllers are responsible for choosing what view to return to the user. You create an actionlink to a controller action and let the action decide what view should be returned to the user. In your case that would be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Menus", "Action", "Controller", null, new { @class = "page-scroll" });
```

Let's say you create a controller named `HomeController` and an action named `Menu`. Let's also add a simple action body:

```
public ActionResult Menu()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then, by convention ASP.NET MVC would look for a view named `Menu.cshtml` in `Views/Home/`. Your actionlink which would link to this action would then be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Menus", "Menu", "Home", null, new { @class = "page-scroll" });
```

Your question is however how to link to a view with href. The `@Html.ActionLink` will do this for you, but if you really want to use href, you can link to an action instead of a view directly for example (if you're using the default MVC route):

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="/Home/Menu">Menus</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, This method is used for redirection.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Menus", "Menu", "Home", new {@class="page-scroll"});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Image As Anchor Tag in Asp.net Mvc 5

When You Want Logo as Action link

```
href="~/"
```

in Layout Page to redirection to Home Page